# How may I loop through a list that contain whitespaces?

Tags: shell-script, whitespace

I need to iterate through my list that sometimes contains whitespaces.

That is the script that I use right now

```
locate .txt > list

for book in $(cat list)
do
    cp "${book}" /mnt/e/BOOK
done
```

I, then, need to copy all .txt files into a designated directory. 
I do not experience any troubles when my list contains

```
/mnt/d/txtfiles/mytextfile1.txt
```

but when the script iterates through say

```
/mnt/d/txtfiles/My text . File2.txt
```

I have a problem with iteration due to the whitespace, while in the list file path is in one line.

Comment: find "/mnt/d/txtfiles" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' -print -exec cp {} "/mnt/e/BOOK" \;

Answer (score 3):

To deal with arbitrary file names, you need your list to use a byte that cannot appear in a file path as the delimiter. The only one that does is the byte 0.

Assuming GNU tools:

```
locate -0 '*.txt' |
  xargs -r0 cp -it /mnt/e/BOOK
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
cp -i ${(0)"$(locate -0 '*.txt')"} /mnt/e/BOOK/
```

(though note that contrary to the `xargs` approach, that may fail if the list of files is too large; `xargs` works around it by running several invocations in that case. You'll also get an error by `cp` if there's no matching file)

Those `0` options or parameter expansion flags to operate on NUL-delimited records instead of lines are specially designed to work with lists of file paths.

Text lines (which on *nix are newline-delimited sequences of a limited number of characters (not bytes)) in general cannot hold file paths as file paths are not guaranteed to be text and could contain newline characters.

Your `$(cat list)`, as it's an unquoted command substitution in list context undergoes IFS-split+glob in most Bourne-like shells and IFS-split only in `zsh`.

Here, you'd need to change the `locate` to `locate -0` so that `list` contains a list of NUL delimited records, tune IFS-split so it splits on NUL and make sure `glob` is not enabled.

However `IFS=$'\0'` would only work in `zsh` as other shells don't support storing NULs in their variables, but in `zsh` it's much better to use the `0` parameter expansion flag (an explicit splitting operator) as shown above than changing `IFS` globally.

In the `bash` shell, with version 4.4 or above, another approach is to do:

```
locate -0 '*.txt' > list &&
  readarray -td '' list < list &&
  cp -i "${list[@]}" /mnt/w/book
```

Or without the `list` file intermediary:

```
readarray -td '' list < <(locate -0 '*.txt') &&
  cp -i "${list[@]}" /mnt/w/book
```

Also note that `locate .txt` would return all entries that have `.txt` anywhere in their path. That could include `/foo.txting/bar.mp4` for instance. `locate '*.txt'` would only return those path that *end* in `.txt`. If you still want to include the `.txt.gz` or `.txt.in` files for instance, but only look for `.txt` in the file name, not full path, use `locate -0 -b .txt`.